# Enforcement of customization types

Tags: customize, customization

When specifying a customizable variable `foo-paths` as follows:

```el
(defcustom foo-paths nil
  "Paths for foo-related things."
  :group 'foo
  :options '(foo-1 foo-2)
  :type '(alist :key-type symbol :value-type (file :must-match t)))
```

There doesn't seem to be any enforcement of the value type in the Customize interface. I can enter any text I want for the values, not just a file (let alone an *existing* file).

Am I missing something here? The [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Simple-Types.html#Simple-Types) says:

> **(file :must-match t)**
>
> The value must be a file name for an existing file. The widget provides completion.

What completion is the widget providing? I don't see any; all I see is a plain text box.

I'm using Emacs 25.1.1.

Comment: (Quick response; no time.) Use `M-TAB` (or `ESC TAB`) to complete a partial file name that you type. I think you're right that the `:must-match` doesn't seem to do what one would expect - completion seems to be lax, not strict. And yet the code (for `widget-file-prompt-value`) does use `(read-file-name prompt2 dir nil must-match file)`, where `must-match` is non-nil. Seems like a bug, but likely someone else here will speak better to this.